# Riverpod: NestedProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

How do you use Nested Provider concept of Provider in Riverpod-

Instead of pushing data through constructor, we used ChangeNotifierProvider.value() (Nested Provider) and then used Model to display data. Provider will by itself push builder data into Model fields

```
class ProductModel with ChangeNotifier {
final String imageUrl;

ProductModel({required this.imageUrl});}
```

from product_grid.dart

```
GridView.builder(
  itemCount: selectedProductList.length,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => 
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: selectedProductList[i],
      child: const ProductItem(),),);
```

to product_item.dart

```
final productModel = Provider.of<ProductModel>(context);

return GridTile(
    child: Image.network(
      productModel.imageUrl,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
```

Comment: I think the question is how to use read data from multiple provider in widget. Am i right?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, Instead of pushing data through constructor, we used ChangeNotifierProvider.value() and then used Model to display data. Provider will by itself push builder data into Model fields

Comment: I can see single provider here, can you include full widget that will reproduce the same issue? you can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have put relevant files here- https://github.com/anmol-me/provider
Want to use provider[ChangeNotifierProvider.value(),] this way in Riverpod

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're after is `ProviderScope`, you can override the value of a provider for its descendants.

Create a provider:

```
final selectedProduct = Provider<ProductModel>((_) => throw UnimplementedError());
```

```
  GridView.builder(
      itemCount: selectedProductList.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => 
        ProviderScope(
          overrides: [selectedProduct.overrideWithValue(selectedProductList[i])],
          child: const ProductItem(),),);
```

then in product_item.dart

```
final productModel = ref.watch(selectedProduct);

return GridTile(
    child: Image.network(
      productModel.imageUrl,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
```

This example has the above implementation in a Todo app if you want to take a look and see how Remi did it:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/todos/lib/main.dart

Hope that helps!